# How to open python sqlite3 .db file in visual basic

Tags: python, database, vb.net, sqlite

Ok so I am more experienced in python so I have been using it to pull information from tables on a wiki page to put into a database so I can use that data in a GUI made in VB.

In the past I was using a CSV file but I just now decided that sqlite3 would be a better option for convenient's sake.

The problem is that (to my knowledge) vb doesn't use .db for its databases. So how would I go about using the .db file from my python script in visual basic for my GUI?

Answer (score 0):

There is an NuGet package that you simply add to your project.

**https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite**

> The official SQLite database engine for both x86 and x64 along with
>   the ADO.NET provider. This package includes support for LINQ and
>   Entity Framework 6.